# How to check and install python if needed through tkinter app

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have made a App using Tkinter and compiled it, everything works fine on my end. However when I sent it to a friend the tkinker app itself ran fine (ie. the gui ran and responded) BUT certain parts didn't work.
So part of the app allows you to ping an ip and that works fine and updates the tkinter Listbox. What doesn't work is running the discord bot and network sniffing using the scapy module.
Now that's most likely because he doesn't have them modules and I can make the app check for them and download them but what I can't figure out is how to check and install pip through the tkinter app as he doesn't even have pip installed. How would I do this the only way I know how to install modules is through pip
SUMMORY QUESTION:
so how do I check and install pip if missing on a tkinter app

Comment: Take a look on [ensurepip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html#module-ensurepip) module.

Comment: This isn't your app's problem to solve. `pip` should be installed first, then *used* to install your [properly packaged application](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/), ensuring that all necessary prerequisites are installed before running the app.

Comment: is there anyway when compiling the py file to a exe to kinda include any files for the imports, maybe places them in the dir folder then the whole folder can be sent and it would work all fine maybe?... Just don't understand how the app can be ran and the PIL/pillow import work fine when he doesn't even have python but other imports can't ie scapy